# Wireless adaptor detects the network but doesn't accept the password (Windows Vista)

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-router, network-adapter

I have an old HP notebook running Windows Vista 32bit. I bought an adaptor (TP-Link TL-WN823N) because of previous network problems, for which I blamed the wireless card. What happens now is that it can list all the available networks, however it can't connect when I type the password. I made a test disabling temporarily the security, bypassing the password, and I'm able to connect! How could I fix that? These are some configurations of the router (in WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK):

Channel: Auto
Mode: 11b/g/n mixed (But I tried several options)
Channel bandwidth: Auto
WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK: Auto (Tried both versions)
Cryptography: AES (TKIP also tested...and failed)
Enable Wireless Router Radio [Ticked]
Enable SSID Broadcast [Ticked]
Enable WDS [Not ticked]

Comment: You should not be using Windows Vista anymore. Aside from being one of the worst operating systems that Microsoft has ever created, it reached EOS 4 years ago. If your computer can't handle Windows 10 consider trying Linux. I recommend [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com) for Linux beginners.

Comment: Fair enough, but I can't do this in the present moment. Since there's the specific fact that it actually works when there's no security, I imagined someone could point me to possible solutions of the problem.